# how to use joins in Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect()

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-select

how can i replace below mysql query to ZF Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect()
 query

```
$sql = "SELECT ps.phone_service_id,ps.phone_service_name,ps.phone_service_Duration,ps.phone_service_type,us.user_preferences_value,ps.user_id FROM phone_service ps,user_preferences us
    WHERE us.phone_service_id = ps.phone_service_id
    AND us.user_preferences_name = 'is_user_package_active'
   AND ps.user_id =".$user_id;
```

i write this one but error occur could you please replace my query to equailent Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect()

```
$select = $DB->select()
              ->from(array('ps' => 'phone_service'
                           'us' => 'user_preferences'),
                array('ps.phone_service_id', 'ps.phone_service_name','ps.phone_service_Duration','ps.phone_service_type','us.user_preferences_value')),
                ->where('us.phone_service_id = ?', 'ps.phone_service_id')
                ->where( 'us.user_preferences_name = ?', 'is_user_package_active')
                ->where( 'us.user_id = ?', $user_id)
                ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

```
$sel = $db->select();
$sel->from(array('p' => 'phone_service'))
    ->join(array('u' => 'user_preferences'), 'u.phone_service_id = p.phone_service_id')
    ->where('u.user_preferences_name = ?', 'is_user_package_active')
    ->where('p.user_id = ?', $user_id);
```

Comment: i need this column only phone_service_id,phone_service_name,phone_service_Duration,phone_service_type,user_id, from phone_service (table) and )user_preferences_value from user_preferences(table),

Comment: in short i want it optmized means that i just need these columns not whole table table column

Comment: Adding the respective columns is easy. Just take a look at the reference manual:http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.columns